# Differentiate between multiple physics bodies on a single sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Say I have three sprites; a player, a triangle, and a square.

The triangle and the square nodes each have a `SKPhysicsBody` assigned while the player node has two - an inner and an outer, of different sizes.

The inner is meant to only register contact with the triangle, while the outer the square.

I have assigned each physics body to the player node:

```
playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [inner, outer])
```

and given each a name:

```
inner.node?.name = "inner"
outer.node?.name = "outer"
```

However, on contact for either in `didBegin`, printing:

```
contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.node?.name
```

displays nil, or the name of the player node if it has one. And this is not the same as printing:

```
contact.bodyB.node?.name
```

Which is for the player node itself. If a physics body has its own name, why can I not identify it in order to distinguish it from another physics body?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't actually done what you were trying to:

> The triangle and the square nodes each have a SKPhysicsBody assigned
>   while the player node has two - an inner and an outer, of different
>   sizes.

when you attempted to assign the 2 physics bodies to the player node with this line:

> `playerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [inner, outer])`

What you actually did was to create a new physics body (which was a union of the physics bodies `inner` and `outer`) and assigned this new physics body (which has no name) and assigned that to your player node.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519736-init

> Creates a physics body by performing a union of a group of
>   volume-based physics bodies.

So the player still only has one physics body (which is neither inner nor outer), which is all a node can have.

One way to get this working is to create 2 new nodes - `playerInner` and `playerOuter` perhaps, each with their own physics body - and join these to create the player node. (`playerInner`  could be a child node of `playerOuter`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So they really do form one body - I had thought that given the ability to add names to each you would still be able to set them apart. A bit misleading really, but will have to settle for separate sprites then.

Comment: Not misleading really - you weren’t assigning names to the physics bodies as SKPhysicsBody does not have a `name` property. Also the 2 physics bodies you created originally still exist with their names, it’s just that a node can only have one physics body (check the `physicsBody` property of a node and you’ll see it’s just an SKPhysicsBody, not an array) and it helpfully allows you to specify a list which it combines into one new one.